# Android Studio builds an old version of the file

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I was tasked with making a page for a project, and for some reason whenever i build a new apk(or hot restart or reload), it keeps the old layout of the page instead of actually showing what i have in my file.

I have commited and pushed the first version to the gitlab project, so maybe that has to do with something. I didn't find much on google, except someone saying that i should delete the build folder in the project, and that didn't help, obviously.

I have also tried all of the standard things like Flutter clean, cache invalidation and rebuilding, but the issue still persists. The issue seems to be only on my computer, i have built the app on my co-workers pc and phone, and it looked like it should.

This is what i need(Dont mind the labels and black lines, ive pulled this image from figma)

[image]

And this is what i get

[image]

Here is my code

```
import 'package:citizen/constants/uiConstants.dart';
import 'package:citizen/constants/uiImages.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:citizen/constants/uiStrings.dart';
import 'package:citizen/constants/uiThemes.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class FirstLoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstLoginPageState createState() => _FirstLoginPageState();
}

class _FirstLoginPageState extends State<FirstLoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _rootWidget(),
    );
  }

  Widget _rootWidget() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: UiConstants.firstLoginPageContentPaddingLR,
          right: UiConstants.firstLoginPageContentPaddingLR),
      child: ScrollConfiguration(
        behavior: MyBehavior(),
        child: ListView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: UiConstants.firstLoginPageLogoMarginBottom,
                    top: kToolbarHeight),
                height: UiConstants.firstLoginPageLogoHeight,
                width: UiConstants.firstLoginPageLogoWidth,
                child: SvgPicture.asset(UiImages.logoAppBarSVG)),
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        UiStrings.firstLoginPageLuchany(context),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: UiConstants.firstLoginPageTitleFontSize,
                            fontFamily: UiTheme.bold,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: UiConstants.firstLoginPageSubtextPaddingTop,
                            bottom:
                                UiConstants.firstLoginPageSubtextPaddingBottom),
                        child: Text(
                          UiStrings.firstLoginPageFirstCommunity(context),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: UiTheme.bold,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      _chatBubbleWidget(
                          UiImages.chatBubbleFemaleProfileIcon6,
                          UiStrings.firstLoginPageOlenaBuyvol(context),
                          UiStrings.firstLoginPageFirstChatBubbleText(context)),
                      _mirroredChatBubbleWidget(
                          UiImages.chatBubbleMaleProfileIcon8,
                          UiStrings.firstLoginPageOlegLyubomyr(context),
                          UiStrings.firstLoginPageSecondChatBubbleText(context),
                          UiConstants.firstLoginPageSubtextPaddingTop),
                      _chatBubbleWidget(
                          UiImages.chatBubbleMaleProfileIcon1,
                          UiStrings.firstLoginPageAndriiGotsul(context),
                          UiStrings.firstLoginPageThirdChatBubbleText(context)),
                      _mirroredChatBubbleWidget(
                          UiImages.chatBubbleFemaleProfileIcon2,
                          UiStrings.firstLoginPageYulyaSavinska(context),
                          UiStrings.firstLoginPageFourthChatBubbleText(context),
                          UiConstants.firstLoginPageLogoMarginBottom),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: UiConstants
                                  .changeUsernameContainerButtonPaddingTB,
                              bottom: UiConstants
                                  .changeUsernameContainerButtonPaddingTB),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: UiConstants.firstLoginPageButtonPaddingTop),
                          width: double.infinity,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                UiConstants.changeUsernameButtonBorderRadius),
                            color: UiTheme.containerButtonColorBlue,
                          ),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text(
                            UiStrings.firstLoginPageButtonLabel(context),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize:
                                    UiConstants.changeUsernameTextFontSize,
                                color: UiTheme.white,
                                fontFamily: UiTheme.MontserratSemiBold),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: UiConstants.changeUsernameContainerPaddingTB,
                            bottom: UiConstants.firstLoginPageLogoMarginBottom),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {},
                          child: Text(
                            UiStrings.firstLoginPageAlreadyHaveAnAccount(
                                context),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: UiTheme.MontserratMedium,
                              fontSize: UiConstants.changeUsernameTextFontSize,
                              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _chatBubbleWidget(String profileIcon, String name, String message) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: UiConstants.firstLoginPageSubtextPaddingTop,
              right: UiConstants.firstLoginPageContentPaddingLR),
          child: Image.asset(
            profileIcon,
            height: UiConstants.firstLoginPageProfileIconHeight,
            width: UiConstants.firstLoginPageProfileIconWidth,
          ),
        ),
        Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: UiConstants.firstLoginPageBubbleIconHeight,
              width: UiConstants.firstLoginPageBubbleIconWidth,
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                UiImages.chatBubbleIcon,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: UiConstants.firstLoginPageBubbleIconTextPaddingLeft,
                  top: UiConstants.firstLoginPageBubbleIconTextPaddingTop),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    name,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: UiTheme.regular,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: UiConstants.firstLoginPageFontSize),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    message,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: UiTheme.regular,
                        fontSize: UiConstants.firstLoginPageFontSize),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _mirroredChatBubbleWidget(
      String profileIcon, String name, String message, double leftPadding) {
    return Transform(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      transform: Matrix4.rotationY(pi),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: UiConstants.firstLoginPageSubtextPaddingTop,
                right: UiConstants.firstLoginPageContentPaddingLR),
            child: Image.asset(
              profileIcon,
              height: UiConstants.firstLoginPageProfileIconHeight,
              width: UiConstants.firstLoginPageProfileIconWidth,
            ),
          ),
          Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: UiConstants.firstLoginPageBubbleIconHeight,
                width: UiConstants.firstLoginPageBubbleIconWidth,
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  UiImages.chatBubbleIcon,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: leftPadding,
                    top: UiConstants.firstLoginPageBubbleIconTextPaddingTop),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Transform(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        transform: Matrix4.rotationY(pi),
                        child: Text(
                          name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: UiTheme.regular,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: UiConstants.firstLoginPageFontSize),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Transform(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationY(pi),
                      child: Text(
                        message,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: UiTheme.regular,
                            fontSize: UiConstants.firstLoginPageFontSize),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Widget buildViewportChrome(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, AxisDirection axisDirection) {
    return child;
  }
}
```

Here is my Flutter Doctor output

```
doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1316], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.0.3 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 4d7946a68d (5 weeks ago), 2021-03-18 17:24:33 -0700
    • Engine revision 3459eb2436
    • Dart version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • SM A310F (mobile) • 192.168.0.136:5555 • android-arm    • Android 7.0 (API 24)
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome             • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.128

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

If i have something else you need to know, tell me in the comments. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You had configured a flavor in middle of development, and working on a dirty state now.

You should run:

```
flutter clean
```

Then update the android studio run configuration to match your flavor (x86 is the emulator one)

[image]